# How to remove the focus from today's date in Angular Material Datepicker?

Tags: angular, angular-material, datepicker

Is it possible to remove the focus on today's date when using Angular Material datepicker? I have tried adding the following properties to mat-datepicker but nothing seems to work and I can't find a way to do this:

- restoreFocus="false"
- [startAt]="null"

```html
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
       <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
       <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
       <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
       <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
```

For example, I don't want the focus/background on 16 in the image below.

[image: Angular material datepicker]

I need to do this because I am trying to use Angular Material datepicker for the users to enter their date of birth and the focus on today's date is irrelevant in this case.

Comment: Did you Find a non-css way to do this? I cannot disable the css entirely as the css is needed to show the focused date. Is there any way to not focus on the today's date at all

Answer (score 1):

apply This class inside style.css file of your project and re run project again.. Basically you need to change default css class implementation.

```
.mat-calendar-body-today:not(.mat-calendar-body-selected):not(.mat-calendar-body-comparison-identical) {
  background-color: rgb(255 255 255) !important;
  border: none !important;
 }
```

Comment: This works. I was trying the same thing but leaving the !important part. Apparently it's necessary to make this work. 

Comment: This didnt work for me.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use startView="multi-year" in the mat-datepicker.

```
<mat-datepicker startView="multi-year" #picker></mat-datepicker>
```

If you like to refer to the documentation, it's here:

https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview

Comment: And how it works without focusing the current date? Which is actually the question is?https://stackblitz.com/edit/fqf2td?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-start-view-example.html,src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-start-view-example.ts